# Switch statement in a React component

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

trying to construct a component that returns several different styled components based on the prop.  Heres what I got:

```
  const Type = ({ props }) => {
  const { right, center } = props;

  switch (props) {
    case props.paragraph:
      return <StyledParagraph right={right} center={center} {...props} />;
    case props.h1:
      return <StyledHeadingOne right={right} center={center} {...props} />;
    case props.h2:
      return <StyledHeadingTwo right={right} center={center} {...props} />;
    case props.h3:
      return <StyledHeadingThree right={right} center={center} {...props} />;
    case props.h4:
      return <StyledHeadingFour right={right} center={center} {...props} />;
    case props.h5:
      return <StyledHeadingFive right={right} center={center} {...props} />;
    case props.h6:
      return <StyledHeadingSix right={right} center={center} {...props} />;
    default:
      return <SetTypeError right={right} center={center} {...props} />;
  }
};
```

Its returning that the props are undefinied.  I'm calling the component like this:

Comment: remove curly braces { } from `const Type = ( { props } )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By writing `({ props })` you are destructuring the `props` property from the props object that is the first parameter of the component, which is equivalent to the following:

```
const Type = (param) => {
  const props = param.props;
  const { right, center } = props;

  // ...
};
```

Just write `(props)` instead to name the props object to `props` and it will work as expected.

```
const Type = (props) => {
  const { right, center } = props;

  // ...
};
```